# C can't initialize a list from a FILE in txt mode

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, fgets

So, my problem is pretty easy, I have to read a set of data (2 strings and a couple of integers) from a txt file. Each data is separate by a \n character. The problem is that instead of actually reading data I get segmentation fault, here's my code for this part:

```
if(head == NULL){ //if the list is empty I want to read data from the file
    fp=fopen("elementi.txt", "r");
    if(fp==NULL) {printf("File non esistente"); exit(2);} //this is just a dumb error line
    else {
        while(fgets(buffer.info.nome,20,fp)!=NULL){
            nl_eat(buffer.info.nome); //this function eliminate the '\n' from the string just read
        fgets(buffer.info.artista,20,fp);
            nl_eat(buffer.info.artista);
            fscanf(fp, "%d%*c", buffer.info.data_uscita.anno);
            fscanf(fp, "%d%*c", buffer.info.data_uscita.mese);
            fscanf(fp, "%d%*c", buffer.info.data_uscita.giorno);
            fscanf(fp, "%f%*c", buffer.info.prezzo);
            addFine(&head,buffer);  //adds the read element at the end of the list      
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to give more information, buffer is type nodo where nodo is

```
typedef struct Data {
int anno;
int mese;
int giorno;
} data;

typedef struct cd {
char nome[25];
char artista [20];
data data_uscita;
float prezzo;
} CD;

struct Nodo{
CD info;
struct Nodo *next;
};

typedef struct Nodo nodo;
```

I'm trying to write a little example, here's the full code: [www.pastebin.com/hLTj8ZG4](http://www.pastebin.com/hLTj8ZG4)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. It's good that your loop tests that `fgets()` works; it would be a whole heap better if you checked that each of the the `fscanf()` calls and the extra `fgets()` also worked. You have an unusual data structure if `buffer.info.data_uscita.anno` is an integer pointer rather than an integer. Similarly with the other numeric inputs. Didn't your compiler warn you? If not, find the compiler warnings (`gcc -Wall` at a bare minimum, if you use `gcc`). Also, the last `fscanf()` leaves the newline to be read by the `fgets()` in the main loop.

Comment: @user3232752 Did you try an analysis tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) ?

Comment: @wesley.mesquita: Nut, meet Sledgehammer; Sledgehammer, this is Nut.  There's no evidence of dynamic memory allocation, which limits the amount that `valgrind` can do to help.  Don't get me wrong; `valgrind` is a wonderful tool.  I'm not sure it would help with this code, though.

Comment: You have to add the remaining code too, consider an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). How are we supposed to know what `buffer.info.nome` is?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the kind reply man! Well I'm not actually testing that the fgets work, rather I'd use the value it returns to execute the while loop! Basically if returns NULL, it means that it didn read anything so I don't have to get any more data. On other fscanf etc, they are not the problem because I tried to comment out them and still I get segmentation fault if I run the program with a non-empty txt file. I rly don't understand what it's going on there, everything else absolutely work. Btw I'm on debian! PS I'm sry for my bad english!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the %*c here? fscanf() will happily scan over whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines) searching for whatever it is looking for.

Comment: @vonbrand Without the `"%*c"`, a following `fgets()` would  consume the remainder of the line and get `"\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

The core dumps are probably because you are passing integers rather than pointers to integers to the `fscanf()` functions.  More or less minimal changes are:

```
nodo buffer;

if (head == NULL)
{
    char const *file = "elementi.txt";
    fp = fopen(file, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File %s non esistente", file);
        exit(2);
    }
    else
    {
        while (fgets(buffer.info.nome, sizeof(buffer.info.nome), fp) != NULL)
        {
            nl_eat(buffer.info.nome);
            if (fgets(buffer.info.artista, sizeof(buffer.info.artista), fp) == NULL)
                break;
            nl_eat(buffer.info.artista);
            if (fscanf(fp, "%d%*c", &buffer.info.data_uscita.anno) != 1 ||
                fscanf(fp, "%d%*c", &buffer.info.data_uscita.mese) != 1 ||
                fscanf(fp, "%d%*c", &buffer.info.data_uscita.giorno) != 1 ||
                fscanf(fp, "%f%*c", &buffer.info.prezzo) != 1)
                break;
            addFine(&head, buffer); 
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Should you be passing `buffer` to `addFine` as a pointer?

You have the 'assignment suppressed' character after the reads.  If there are no trailing blanks on the line, those will read the newline. However, there's no way for you program to detect whether they were successful or not.  You would probably do better to assign the character so you can test whether you got a character and if so, whether it was a newline.  If necessary, you can gobble characters to end of line.

If you're still getting core dumps, then we need more context.  The problem might be in `addFine()`.  One way to help debug is to print out the data as it is read.  This checks that the program is seeing the data you expect it to see.